# calculating the number of tries needed to successfully hit targets with different probability each

Tags: probability, statistics

Currently designing a game. I am trying to solve a problem, but I am not sure which formulas should I apply. I know to calculate the result step by step but it's time consuming and may not give the right result.  Here is the problem:

We have an army of 5000 players. Each player has a different probability to be hit by a bullet, from 0.01% to 1% per player, respectively 0.0001 and 0.01, in final all 5000 of them totaling to 100%, respectively 1.

Each player can take minimum 3 bullets before getting killed, and maximum the amount of bullets already fired by the enemy since the start of the game multiplied with the player's probability to be hit by a bullet +1.

Example: The enemy fired 10000 bullets since start of the game, so a player with the probability to be hit of 0.01 can take 10000 * 0.01 = 100 + 1 = 101 bullets to get this player killed. If the result of this formula is < 3 (start of the game, very small amount of total bullets fired or very small player probability), value 3 will prevail (a player cannot take less than 3 bullets under any circumstances).

Question: how many bullets does the enemy have to fire in order to kill 10% of the players, 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% ? What are the formulas to find these out? I think I might have to combine different formulas because of the random probability for each player to be hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model each player's hits by a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) The probability that player has taken $k$ hits is $p(k)=\frac {\lambda ^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$with $\lambda$ equal to the expected number of hits for that player.  If the enemy has fired $1000$ bullets, a player with $1\%$ chance of getting hit will have an expected number of hits of $1000 \cdot 0.01=10$, so you use $\lambda=10$.  A player with $0.02\%$ chance of getting hit has $\lambda = 0.2$  For a given number of bullets, you can compute the $\lambda$s for all the different hit probabilities in the population.  For $\lambda=1.5$, the chance of not getting hit three times is $1-(p(0)+p(1)+p(2))=1-e^{-1.5}(1+\frac {1.5^1}{1!}+\frac {1.5^2}{2!})\approx 0.19$ so about one fifth of your players with $\lambda =1.5$ will be dead.  For $\lambda=0.5$ only $1.5\%$ will die. You can use these figures with your distribution of hit probabilities to compute the overall kill rate.

Comment: Awesome. Expanding formulas for better understanding. How can I estimate the total number of bullets required to kill 100% of the players?

Comment: Killing the last one is much more variable than killing fractions like half.  Say you have 5000 players each with a $0.01\%$ chance of being hit (plus some others with higher chances, but they will be long gone).  At $\lambda=11$ they have $0.0002$ chance of survival, so you expect one left.  This is after $110,000$ bullets.  There will be substantial variation-sometimes you will already have none, sometimes you will have 2 or 3 left.  You can compute the expected value for the number of bullets required, but it is probably not very useful.

Comment: I glossed over one thing that will not affect these calculations much. You specified that each bullet hits one player, but I considered each player to be hit with the given probability independently.  For a large number of players, it won't matter, but if you had two players each with a hit probability of $1/2$, you would guarantee that each bullet hit one or the other.  I would hit both players with probability $1/4$, neither with probability $1/4$ and each one alone with probability $1/4$.  The chance for a given player to be hit is still $1/2$, but in your model they are anticorrelated.

Comment: This is what allows me to simply consider that each player has, say, 1000 chances of $0.01\%$ to be hit without considering what happens to the rest.

Comment: That is correct. Even if the player has 0.001 probability to be hit, the enemy can target that player explicitly and have 100% probability to hit him, except the enemy will have to fire TOTAL number of already fired bullets since start of the game multiplied with player's probability to be hit +1. What I am trying to figure out is how many bullets will the enemy need overall to kill all my players.

Comment: If the enemy can target players, you need to consider the strategies the enemy might use.  I was certainly assuming that after the enemy had killed half the players, the chance of a given surviving player getting hit does not increase.  You need to specify how the hit chance increases with enemy targetting.  This will make the analysis much more complicated.  A strategy example, if all the players deal the same damage to the enemy, it may make sense for the enemy to start by targetting the ones that are easy to hit to reduce the damage rate as quickly as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your time in this. Consider this. If the enemy shoots randomly, each player has the chance to be hit as described first time. But if the enemy does not shoot randomly, he can select player x and hit him with 100% chances to be hit unlimited times (until the player dies, proportional with the total amount for bullets already fired by the enemy and that player's hit chance when the enemy shoots random).

Comment: The enemy can take the players in whatever order he wants, and shoot them with 100% hit chance, the only side effect will be that as he shoots more players the last remaining players will need so many bullets to be killed (because the total amount of already fired bullets) and the enemy will run out of ammo. Which is why I am trying to discover a reasonable number here.

Comment: If the enemy can target players and can hit only one player per bullet (as you said at the start), he needs one bullet per player.  I think you need to consider your game mechanics carefully before trying to compute this.  It seemed to start that the enemy could not target, but that it was random.

Comment: Each player can take min. 3 bullets as described from the start. And after 1000 players, the 1001 one will need 3000 * 0.01 = 30 bullets. Where 0.01 is the players probability to be hit randomly. So after playing some more the enemy will need more and more bullets, does this make sense?

Comment: According to your previous comment, the enemy can hit a player with $100\%$ chance, so would need only $3$ times as many bullets as players.  I lost the factor $3$ last time.  If the enemy can target an individual player with $100\%$ chance, he should just hit each player $3$ times and move on to the next.